# How do i add <br> automatically in textarea when a user press "enter" key?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how would i approach on adding 
`<br>`
tag automatically when a user types inside textarea ? Probably using javascript or php (because im developing my web app using laravel) ? Would i need wysiwyg editor for such simple task ?

Comment: use `nl2br` function in php

Comment: adding `<br/>` to what ? What did you tried ? Where is your code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. Wait until the form is submitted then add them. With PHP as a backend for example you would use nl2br

```
$my_var = nl2br($_REQUEST['textarea_name']);
```

Comment: Or conversely use it when data is rendered if need to edit it again as text at later time

Comment: @charlietfl I agree. Unless there's a compelling reason to store that value with the added markup, this should be done at the presentation level, when showing the text.

Comment: Exactly what i need! I agree, Im doing it in the view instead of when i store it to the backend. Many downvotes tho im sorry for the people that i offend! I need to wait a couple of minutes before i can mark this question to be answered :D